# two way client server communication

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, websocket

I have an existing server logic in place. I have tried fetch calls in my client side react native app and they seem to work well. But this is a chat app, so if anyone sends a message, I want that to show up in the chatroom for all users logged in.

I do not wish to make any changes in the server. Is there a way to implement client polling using any javascript library ? I looked up websockets, but I am not sure if websocket implementation is required on the server too or only client will work ? I also looked up firebase, but it looks like firebase provides its own database.

The only other option I know of is polling, basically calling the fetch method every few seconds , by using setTimeOut.

Comment: I am confused about the question. It sounds like you want your server to function differently but you don't want to make any changes to it. This question is tagged firebase but its unclear if your server is firebase. Fire base is a realtime database. If your server is firebase then just switch to snapshots and everything will work in realtime.

Comment: My server is a basic nodejs implementation, I cannot change any of the server implementation. Also the API exposed is fixed. What I am looking for is a good way of polling on the client side or equivalent. I looked up videos on using firebase and websockets, but for both I see server and client changes. So can’t use either. ( unless server changes are optional, which I am not sure of).

Comment: Just poll your existing server from the client at a regular interval. If not then, you could write another server that polls your untouchable server and then use websockets in the new wrapper server.